# Que signifie "prior" en français dans un contexte financier ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, finance

Je découvre un peu la prédiction financière à partir [d'un article](https://towardsdatascience.com/stock-prediction-in-python-b66555171a2) et je voulais savoir ce que voulait dire *prior*. Dans l'article on le retrouve 34 fois. Pour moi cela signifiais la préposition *avant* en Français mais j'ai de sérieux doute en particulier à la lecture de cette phrase :

- *A higher prior creates a model with more* : un plus grand avant ?

Même si ca faisait sens pour :

- *The changepoint prior scale* : le point de changement avant la sélection.

Ca me paraîtrait bizarre que ca puisse signifier un *prieur* ...
Voilà, j'ai vraiment besoin de vos lumières !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*étonnant que cela signifie un prieur* ?... Bof... dans ton article... il est bien aussi question de *prophète*... alors... ;-)

Blague à part, si tu cherches à en savoir plus sur ce point, intéresse toi à l'**Inférence bayésienne**. Car c'est dans ce contexte que on peut comprendre ce *prior*.

L'inférence bayésienne permet de calculer la *posterior probabilité* d'un événement en fonction d'une *prior probability* et d'autres trucs.

Pour la *prior probability*, le français parlera de probabilité... **à priori.**

(Bon et il s'agit plus souvent d'une *loi de probabilité* que d'une probabilité => formellement *prior* = loi de probabilité à priori.

Comment: Oui, avec plaisir ! J'aimerai bien commencer mais je ne sais pas par quoi ? Vous avez des recommendations de cours en ligne ou de livre ? J'ai un Master II en IA mais les mathématiques ne sont pas forcément mon point le plus fort.

Comment: Je n'ai pas cherché sur le net pour savoir s'il existait des versions libres. Cela dit, chaleureusement recommandés aux masters : *Le raisonnement Bayésien* d'Éric Parent et ? ou *Le choix Bayésien* de Robert. (Tu pourras survoler le premier sur gglivres... il manque quand même pas mal de pages...)